# is there a way to lock down an android phone to a specific IP range (i.e spotify IP addresses only)?

Tags: security

Is there a way to lock down an android phone to a specific IP range (i.e spotify IP addresses only)?

We want our daughter to listen to spotify, but not access the internet in any other way. Right now, we have locked the phone down to spotify only.

However, for any links provided in descriptions in spotify, when she "clicks" on them, the browser opens.

Hence, we are keen to basically just lock it down to allowed IP addresses only. To keep our policing easy.

Comment: No, Android devices don't have that ability without root and custom unofficial applications.  Plus Spotify no longer uses specific IP ranges like they did several years ago, they have hosted servers all around the globe, and Spotify no longer provides those IP ranges to the public (filtering is done by content type now days). My suggestion would be to look into if your device has Parental Controls enabled.

Comment: What would be a better way to only allow internet access to spotify? We locked with parental controls to only give access to spotify, but clicking on any link in spotify opens the browser and the browser basically means unlimited access to the internet.

Comment: You could, of course, put something in between the phone and the internet that restricts it to a specific IP range.

Comment: Theoretically a special VPN app (or service) could restrict network requests to certain IPs. However you should consider that Spotify is a service that AFAIK runs in the Amazon cloud, that means there are a large number of servers be used and their IP can change at any time. Also other AWS services may have a similar or even the same IP if common AWS servers are used.

Comment: This is just an idea, but maybe use a vpn directly connected to spotify

Comment: Use a parental control (some Kiosk app I guess) app (a separate app, not Google Play Parental Control) to restrict app access to Spotify app only

Comment: Perhaps a phone is not the proper device for this application... There are several MP3/Streaming players that can be purchased on sites like Amazon, that would only give access to music or streaming services.